# Merge k sorted arrays using C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to merge k (1 <= k <= 16) sorted arrays into one sorted array. This is for a homework assignment and the Professor requires that this be done using an O(n) algorithm. Merging 2 arrays is no problem and I can do it easily using an O(n) algorithm. I feel that what my professor is asking is undoable for n arrays with an O(n) algorithm.

I am using the below algorithm to split the array indices and running InsertionSort on each partition. I could save these start and end indices into a 2D array. I just don't see how the merging can be done using O(n) because this is going to require more than one loop. If it is possible, does anyone have any hints. I'm not looking for actual code, just a hint as to where I should start/

```
int chunkSize = round(float(arraySize) / numThreads);
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    int start = i * chunkSize;
    int end = start + chunkSize - 1;
    if (i == numThreads - 1) {
        end = arraySize - 1;
    }

    InsertionSort(&array[start], end - start + 1);
}
```

**EDIT:** The requirement is that the algorithm be O(n) where n is the number of elements in the array. Also, I need to solve this without using a min heap.

**EDIT #2:** Here is an algorithm I came up with. The problem here is that I'm not storing the result of each iteration back into the original array. I could just copy all of it back in for a loop but that would be expensive. Is there any way I can do this, other than using something `memcpy`? In the below code, `indices` is a 2D array [numThreads][2] where array[i][0] is the start index and array[i][1] is the end index of the ith array.

```
void mergeArrays(int array[], int indices[][2], int threads, int result[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < threads - 1; i++) {
        int resPos = 0;
        int lhsPos = 0;
        int lhsEnd = indices[i][1];
        int rhsPos = indices[i+1][0];
        int rhsEnd = indices[i+1][1];

        while (lhsPos <= lhsEnd && rhsPos <= rhsEnd) {
            if (array[lhsPos] <= array[rhsPos]) {
                result[resPos] = array[lhsPos];
                lhsPos++;
            } else {
                result[resPos] = array[rhsPos];
                rhsPos++;
            }
            resPos++;
        }

        while (lhsPos <= lhsEnd) {
            result[resPos] = array[lhsPos];
            lhsPos++;
            resPos++;
        }

        while (rhsPos <= rhsEnd) {
            result[resPos] = array[rhsPos];
            rhsPos++;
            resPos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can trivially merge n arrays with n-1 = O(n) merge operations: merge arrays 1 and 2, then 3 with the result, then 4 with the result from that, ... Is this what your professor wants?

Comment: The complexity indeed depends on k, but in your problem k is limited by a constant, so you can just substitute 16 for k and get the required O(n).

Answer (score 6):

You can merge **K** sorted arrays in one sorted array with `O(N*log(K))` algorithm, using priority queue with K entries, where **N** is overall number of elements in all arrays.

If `K` is considered **as constant value** (it is limited by 16 in your case), then complexity is `O(N)`.

Note again: **N** is number of elements in my post, not number of arrays.
It is impossible to merge arrays in O(K) - simple copy takes O(N)

Answer (score 2):

Using the facts you provided:
 (1) n is the number of arrays to to merge;
 (2) the arrays to be merged are already sorted;
 (3) the merge needs to be of order n, that is linear in the number of arrays 
    (and NOT linear in the number of elements in each array, as you might mistakenly think at first sight).

Use the analogy of merging 4 sorted piles of cards, low to high, face up. You would pick the card with the lowest face value from one of the piles and put it (face down) on the merged deck, until all piles are exhausted.
For your program: keep a counter for each array for the number of elements you have already transferred to the output. This is at the same time an index to the next element in each array NOT merged in the output. Pick the smallest element that you find at one of these locations. You have to lookup the first waiting element in all the arrays for that, so that is of order n.

Also, I don't understand why the answer from MoB got up-votes, it does not answer the question.

Comment: *Also, I don't understand why the answer from @MBo got up-votes, it does not answer the question.*. The reason is simple, he is right. And by the way this is the most efficient way to solve the problem being asked. Please read his answer again.

Comment: have you seen the last edit on the question? there was a mix-up initially, OP indeed does want the O(n) where n is total number of elements, and k <= 16 is the fixed number of arrays.

Comment: @psyco - Yes, I know a priority queue is the most efficient way to do a multiway merge (probably known since the late 1970's), but that was not the answer to the question posted by the OP. I sticked to the bad question, linearity in number of arrays, rather than offering a solution for multiway merge sort. OP modified his question by putting K as the number of arrays and asking for a merge of complexity O(N), and not O(K). Now OP still has to clarify what he means by O(N). His question still ends with "I feel that what my professor is asking is undoable for n arrays with an O(n) algorithm".

Comment: @FonsVanAssche Please see my edits. I've also added an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (pseudocode)

```
input array[k][n]
init indices[k] = { 0, 0, 0, ... }
init queue = { empty priority queue }

for i in 0..k:
    insert i into queue with priority (array[i][0])

while queue is not empty:
    let x = pop queue
    output array[x, indices[x]]
    increment indices[x]
    insert x into queue with priority (array[x][indices[x]])
```

This can probably be simplified further in C. You would have to find a suitable queue implementation to use though as there are none in libc.

Complexity for this operation:

"while queue is not empty" => O(n)

"insert x into queue ..." => O(log k)

=> O(n log k)

Which, if you consider k = constant, is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

After sorting the k sub-arrays (the method doesn't matter), the code does a k-way merge. The simplest implementation does k-1 compares to determine the smallest leading element of each of the k arrays, then moves that element from it's sub-array to the output array and gets the next element from that array. When the end of an array is reached, the algorithm drops down to a (k-1) way merge, then (k-2) way merge, finally there's just one sub-array left and it's copied. This will be O(n) time since k-1 is a constant.

The k-1 compares can be sped up by using a minimum heap (which is how some priority queues are implemented), but it's still O(n), with just a smaller constant. The heap needs to be initialized at the start, then updated each time an element is removed and a new one added.